# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Field Creating New Version With Each Stage of Workflow

Tags: workflow, version-history

I recently created a workflow that is attached to a document set. The workflow goes through a number of stages to create, update or delete a calendar item in a separate list. When the workflow was published, it created a new Column in the list that displays the stage the workflow is in and provides a link to the workflows. This is fine and can be hidden if needed. The problem comes when a document is added or updated in the library. Because versions are being tracked on the documents, when a new document is added, it creates version 1.0; however at this point, the workflow described above kicks off and although it does not run all the way through, it still creates a new version of the document with the first stage where it started and ended. One would think that the version would be associated with the Document itself and not the list, but when the list gets updated by the Workflow, it creates a new version. If I update the triggered item on the list (the due date), it then triggers the workflow and runs through multiple stages, and a new version is created at each stage of the workflow. Is there a way to prevent the workflow field from creating a new version of the document?